# Refresh list after adding an item with jQuery UI sortable plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

Alright so I have a nested sortable list, each item is therefore both a container and a sortable element.

The problem I am facing is that, whenever I add a new element, I want jQuery to refresh its internal state with the new item. 
According to the documentation, one has to call the sortable method passing as parameter 'refresh', but still I can't make it work.

Sample code:
http://jsfiddle.net/X5sBm/

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var list = $('#mycontainer ul').sortable({
        connectWith: '#mycontainer ul',
        placeholder: 'myplaceholder'
    });

    function addElement(text) {
        $('#mycontainer > ul').append('<li>' + text + '<ul></ul></li>');
        list.sortable('refresh');
    }

    addElement('yolo');
});
```

HTML:

```
<div id="mycontainer">
    <ul>
        <li>
            Some text
            <ul>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
            Some text 2
            <ul>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#mycontainer > ul {
    display: block;
}

#mycontainer > ul ul {
    min-height: 10px;
    padding-left: 20px;
}

.myplaceholder {
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

Try to drag one pre existing item under the newly added one, you won't be able to do so even after the refresh.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found a cheap fix:

I call sortable again on the same tag reinitialising the Sortable plugin like so:

```
$('#mycontainer ul').sortable({
    connectWith: '#mycontainer ul',
    placeholder: 'myplaceholder'
});
```

and it works.

Comment: This helped me, I didn't realize what I was doing:  I was adding a brand new *container* element, rather than adding to a parent sortable container.  That new element was never set up, and my console actually notified me of that!  After pulling my head from my posterior, I realized this.  So, I created an Object that was at a higher scope for the sortable options, and then I can reuse those options after my AJAX call.  I hope this helps someone else!

Comment: Is this really valid though? I am having the same problem, where it seems that `refresh` does nothing, other than returning an error (which is not fixable btw, it just seems to not work with nested elements). It seems a bit unpractical to end up copy-pasting the whole `sortable()` function again, since mine is bigger than those 4 rules of code as in the example above. Anyone who might have a better answer?

Answer (score 0):

The key understanding and take-away is to make the dynamically created `<ul></ul>` initialized with the sortable options. I suggest making an `options` object for easy re-use.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    const container = $('#mycontainer ul');
    const options = {
        connectWith: '#mycontainer ul',
        placeholder: 'myplaceholder'
    };
    container.sortable(options);
    
    function addElement(text) {
        let newListItem = $('<li>').text(text);
        newListItem.append($('<ul>').sortable(options)); // <- key concept
        $('#mycontainer > ul').append(newListItem);
        //container.sortable('refresh');
        
    }
    
    addElement('yolo');
    
});
```

```css
#mycontainer > ul {
    display: block;
}

#mycontainer ul ul {
    min-height: 10px;
    padding-left: 20px;
}

.myplaceholder {
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="mycontainer">
      <ul>
          <li>
              Some text
              <ul>
              </ul>
          </li>
          <li>
              Some text 2
              <ul>
              </ul>
          </li>
          <li>
              Some text 3
              <ul>
              </ul>
          </li>
      </ul>
  </div>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```