# jQuery UI Sortable and moving elements between lists

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I want to grab items from lists and drag them to other blank lists.

This is the HTML structure:

```html
<div class="structure">
  <div id="row1" class="connected"></div>
  <div id="row2" class="connected">
    <div class="item">Item 1</div>
  </div>
  <div id="row3" class="connected"></div>
  <div id="row4" class="connected">
    <div class="item">Item 2a</div>
    <div class="item">Item 2b</div>
    <div class="item">Item 2c</div>
  </div>
  <div id="row5" class="connected"></div>
  <div id="row6" class="connected">
    <div class="item">Item 3a</div>
    <div class="item">Item 3b</div>
  </div>
  <div id="row7" class="connected"></div>
</div>
```

There are empty `<ul>` where you can put any item in. After that it creates new empty `<ul>` before and after to drag other items to.

This is my javascript

```js
$( function() {
  $(".structure div").sortable({
    placeholder: "ui-state-highlight",
    connectWith: ".connected",
    items:       "> div",

    receive:     function (event, ui) {

      var targetRowID = $(this).attr("id");
      var itemsTargetRow = $("#"+ targetRowID +" .item").length;

      if( itemsTargetRow == 1 ) {
        function uniqueID() {
          return Math.random().toString(36).substr(2, 5);
        };

        $("#"+ targetRowID)
          .before('<div id="row'+ uniqueID() +'" class="connected"></div>')
          .after('<div id="row'+ uniqueID() +'" class="connected"></div>');
      }
    },

    stop: function (event, ui) {

      var fromRow = $(this).attr("id");
      var isRowEmpty = $("#"+ fromRow +" .item").length;

      if( isRowEmpty == 0 )
      {
        $("#"+ fromRow).next().remove();
        $("#"+ fromRow).remove();
      }
    }
  }).disableSelection();
});
```

The problem:

When I dropped an item to an empty list, I can't drag that item anywhere else anymore.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok here's your problem

JQuery starts with the page load and finds all of the areas to 'connect' with. When you add more divs JQuery does not realize there is new areas to allow drag and drop.

Solution? you need to refresh your JQuery, somehting like this:

```
var refresh = function(){
   $( function() {
  $(".structure div").sortable({
    placeholder: "ui-state-highlight",
    connectWith: ".connected",
    items:       "> div",

    receive:     function (event, ui) {

      var targetRowID = $(this).attr("id");
      var itemsTargetRow = $("#"+ targetRowID +" .item").length;

      if( itemsTargetRow == 1 ) {
        function uniqueID() {
          return Math.random().toString(36).substr(2, 5);
        };

        $("#"+ targetRowID)
          .before('<div id="row'+ uniqueID() +'" class="connected"></div>')
          .after('<div id="row'+ uniqueID() +'" class="connected"></div>');
         refresh();
      }
    },

    stop: function (event, ui) {

      var fromRow = $(this).attr("id");
      var isRowEmpty = $("#"+ fromRow +" .item").length;

      if( isRowEmpty == 0 )
      {
        $("#"+ fromRow).next().remove();
        $("#"+ fromRow).remove();
      }
    }
  }).disableSelection();
}); 
}
```

Here's a work in progress example:
http://codepen.io/nilestanner/pen/grJJmJ

You can also look at this answer for more help:
[Refresh list after adding an item with jQuery UI sortable plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22560724/refresh-list-after-adding-an-item-with-jquery-ui-sortable-plugin)