# jQuery UI sortable refresh doesn't work after appending new element

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

So once I append a new list of elements they are no longer sortable. I've tried to use sortable("refresh") but it still doesnt work.

```
$(function() {
    $(".test").on('click', function(event) {
      $(this).parent().append('<ul class="sortList"><li>123</li></ul>');
      $(".sortList").sortable('refresh');
    })

    $(".sortList").sortable({
        connectWith: ".sortList"
    }).disableSelection();
});
```

Here is a jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/6nL0rm1a/5/ showing my problem. As you see if you click the button a new list is added. But you cant sort/drag & drop its items to other lists.

I want the items of the appended list to be draggable & droppable. Also sortable.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Refresh list after adding an item with jQuery UI sortable plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22560724/refresh-list-after-adding-an-item-with-jquery-ui-sortable-plugin)

Comment: @Roy Hey. Should've mentioned it in the post but that solution didnt work for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First attempt, adding the sorted when appending the list.

```
  $(function() {
    $(".test").on('click', function(event)      
     {
            $(this).parent().append('<ul class="sortList"><li>123</li></ul>').children().sortable({
        connectWith: ".sortList"
    }).disableSelection();
    })

    $(".sortList").sortable({
        connectWith: ".sortList"
    }).disableSelection();
});
```